# Blend Mode like Photoshop's Overlay

Tags: actionscript-3, image, overlay, photoshop

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to the Overlay blend mode between two layers in photoshop in Flash. It sounds simple enough, but BlendMode.OVERLAY produces a distinctly different result than what is seen in photoshop using the same two images. I was wondering if anyone knows a good way to mimic Photoshop's overlay.

Comment: the difference you are seeing is probably caused by the color profile you are using in Photoshop.  both programs use the same algorithm for basic blending like overlay.  can you provide screenshots contrasting the two versions?  there may also be adjustment layers in your photoshop file that is affecting the image.

Comment: How are you applying the filters? It should probably only be applied to the "upper" image.

Comment: Yes, only the top layer is being set to the overlay blend mode in Photoshop/Flash. I'll check the color profiles - is Photoshop CMYK normally?

Comment: It doesn't appear that the color profile was the problem, however, the problem really isn't relevant anymore, so no one needs to look for a solution if they don't want to :^)

Comment: Perhaps it's proper to close the question then? Just my two-sense..

Answer (score 0):

If your graphics have transparency, I think it has something to do with pre-multiplied vs post-multiplied bitmaps. Getting Photoshop-like results will require you to get down and dirty with BitmapData. Try reading http://quasimondo.com